# Turning a car field into a factor, in the right order

Tags: r

I have a column that looks like this:

```
 $ Stage     : chr  "final" "final" "final" "final" ...
```

The values are final, first, resub.

I want to convert it into a factor, specifically ordered like this:

```
first, resub, final
```

Why that order? Because I use it in a ggplot later and they are displaying in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can also convert to factor and order as you want in one of the layers in ggplot() function but it can be done earlier. Everything is easier with `dplyr`.

```
>str(mydf$anim3) # one column from my df 
 chr [1:5] "A" "A" "B" "C" "C"

>mydf <- mydf %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.factor)
>str(mydf$anim3)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 2 3 3

>levels(mydf3$anim3) #order of our levels
 [1] "A" "B" "C"

>str(factor(mydf$anim3,levels(mydf3$anim3)[c(3,1,2)])) #you can order levels whatever you want using this
 Factor w/ 3 levels "C","A","B": 2 2 3 1 1
```